# NetSuite - how to make a standard item field searchable

Tags: search, netsuite, erp

We are currently unable to use the NetSuite global search to find items by purchase or sales description. I tried creating a custom field that defaults to the purchase description, but if I enable "Store Value", then there is no data in the field and if I disable "Store Value", then "Show in Global Search" is disabled. Any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a script or workflow to set the field whenever someone changes the description. You can then use a mass update to backfill the existing item records.

Comment: To see examples of code for setting this up go to https://github.com/BKnights/KotN-Netsuite?files=1 and review the `expose*` scripts